# Optimality conditions for quadratic constrained optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

There is an optimization problem of the form,

$\min v^Tv + w^T \mathbf{diag(x)}^{-1} w$

subject to constraints:

$v+Bw=Ax+b$, and $x \succeq 0 $,

where, $v \in \mathbb{R^m}$, and  $w,x \in \mathbb{R^n}$.
It should be noted that the optimization is solved assuming $x\succeq 0$ as fixed, and solving over variables $v$ and $w$.

Now, in the textbook [Boyd, Convex Opt.], the optimality condition for this problem is given as,

$v = \upsilon$, and $w=\mathbf{diag(x)}B^T\upsilon$, for some $\upsilon$.

However, I am unable to see how KKT conditions reach these given optimality condition. Is there any hint on how to proceed?

Comment: You could note that $v=(Ax+b)-Bw$ and eliminate the constraint and $v$ entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of grinding through the details.

Let $y=(v,w)$ and write the problem as
$\min \{ {1 \over 2} y^T \Lambda y \mid Hy=c \}$,
where
$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & \operatorname{diag}(x)^{-1} \end{bmatrix} $,
$H = \begin{bmatrix} I & B \end{bmatrix} $, $c=Ax+b$.

The KKT conditions give
$\Lambda y + H^T \mu = 0$ for some $\mu$. Expanding $y, \Lambda, H^T$ and a little algebra gives the result.